# How can I create an equation for a pattern?

Tags: linear-algebra, pattern-recognition, pattern-matching

How can I generally create an equation from a pattern?

Take for example this pattern:

{X = 15, Y = 0}, {X = 16, Y = 1}, {X = 16, Y = 2}, {X = 17, Y = 3}, {X = 17, Y = 4}

---

**This pattern could be resolved to:**

X = 15 + (Y / 2)

---

I tried WolframAlpha but couldn't find any widget that helps me do this.
Is there an easy way to create an equation from a pattern?

Comment: guessing and then proving is really the only way. It is generally almost impossible to go from a few data points (or even a lot) to an equation. I think you could use matricies to find the line of best fit which might answer your question?

Comment: depending on your goal, you could interpolate a polynomial through the points. But it all depends on what you are trying to do

Comment: Plot the points and look at them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A manual way is to use `Excel`.

Enter the data as table. Convert the table data into a graph chart.

For linear cases, add a `linear trend line`. `Excel` will also supply the formula for the trend line:

[image]

`Excel` offers a [range of trend lines](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Choosing-the-best-trendline-for-your-data-1bb3c9e7-0280-45b5-9ab0-d0c93161daa8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1): exponential, linear, logarithmic, polynomial, power, moving average.

In your example, the same `X` values appear for more than one `Y` value. Therefore, `Y` rather than `X` should be selected as independent variable. But this may be different for other patterns.

Comment: Thanks so much!